# How to set values to data class if some size is specified in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a `data class` in `kotlin` like this:

```
data class myDataClass(val myArr: ArrayList<Char>)
```

Now, suppose I create an instance of it as follows:

```
val myData = myDataClass(x)    // x is an integer; 1 <= x <= 9
```

I want that `myData` should have the following data:

```
println(myData.myArr)
// [A, B, C, D, ...]
```

Comment: It's hard to suppose you create an instance of the class like that when it results in a compilation error....

Comment: @Clay07g sorry for my bad english, I meant that I should be able to create an instance of the class like that so that it should give me the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible:

```
data class myDataClass(val myArr: ArrayList<Char>) {
    constructor(i: Int) : this(ArrayList((0..i).map { ('A' + it).toChar() }))
}
```

But the truth is, it's a pretty strange code