# How to initialise 'MutableMap' from constructor of data class in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a `data class` which has a `constructor` like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57514631/8455110)):

```
data class MyDataClass (
    val myArr: ArrayList<Char>
) {
    constructor(n: Int): 
        this(
            ArrayList((0 until n).map { ('A' + it).toChar() })
        )
}
```

As an example:

```
println(MyDataClass(3).myArr)
```

would give me:

```
[A, B, C]
```

I want to modify my `data class` further like this:

```
data class MyDataClass (
    val myArr: ArrayList<Char>,
    val myMap: MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<String, String>>
) {
    constructor(n: Int): 
    this(
            ArrayList((0 until n).map { ('A' + it).toChar() }),
            mutableMapOf()
        )
}
```

Now, when I print the `myMap` like:

```
println(MyDataClass(3).myMap)
```

I get:

```
{}
```

Now, I want that instead of getting an empty `MutableMap` for `myMap`, I want to get a `MutableMap` like this:

```
println(MyDataClass(3).myMap)
```

```
{A={}, B={}, C={}}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: So you want a map of maps?

Comment: yes, and all the array items of `myArr` should be its keys

Comment: `(0 until n).map { ('A' + it) to mutableMapOf<YourType>()}.toMutableMap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Extracting the init logic into a companion function:

```
data class MyDataClass(
    val myArr: ArrayList<Char>,
    val myMap: MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<String, String>>
) {
    constructor(n: Int) : this(
        ArrayList(foo(n)),
        foo(n).map { it to mutableMapOf<String, String>() }.toMap().toMutableMap()
    )

    companion object {
        fun foo(n: Int) = (0 until n).map { ('A' + it) }
    }
}
```

2. Add intermediate constructor

```
data class MyDataClass(
    val myArr: ArrayList<Char>,
    val myMap: MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<String, String>>
) {
    constructor(n: Int) : this(ArrayList((0 until n).map { ('A' + it) }))

    constructor(list: ArrayList<Char>) : this(
        list,
        list.map { it to mutableMapOf<String, String>() }.toMap().toMutableMap()
    )
}
```

Comment: what is `toObjectMap()`? your code is not working here at (https://play.kotlinlang.org/)

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh, sorry it's a shortcut on my env for `.toMap().toMutableMap()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the reasons behind this choice of constructor params, but I would say you only need one of your constructors, since everything is built from the `int` param you take in the explicit ctor. Going from there, I would simplify the code to look like this:

```
data class Thingamajigg(val n: Int) {
    val myArr: ArrayList<Char> = arrayListOf()
    val myMap: MutableMap<Char, MutableMap<String, String>> = mutableMapOf()

    init {
        (0..n).forEach { myArr.add('A' + it) }
        myArr.forEach { myMap[it] = mutableMapOf() }
    }
}
```

Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Reason is that I don't need to build from only `int` param every time

Comment: Alright, I think you can adapt my code to your needs, should be simple enough. Tell me if you need me to edit it :)